# dataframe calculations cause more than one output

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with grades. I am trying to find the percentage of people who get an A in a class. To do this, I do the following

```
df["PercentageA"] = (df["A+"] + df["A"])/(df["Students"])
```

When I do this, for all the classes, here is the output in the PercentageA column:
694 0.7416332 Name: PerA, dtype: float64

The only correct part of this is the "0.7416332"
I do not need the 694 (I assume this is the index) or the Name and Float type

How do I remove these and just have .7416332?

I tried to.list(), to_string(), .values, but these all make objects that I cannot compare with nlargest and mean(). I need just the float, nothing else

Comment: can you share small chunk of your input data ?

Comment: @nisakova i dont think the question makes any sense; it's just a newbie wondering why when they write `df["PercentageA"]` they are getting the series with its metadata

Comment: @nisakova sure,  here is a link to the data https://github.com/wadefagen/datasets/blob/master/gpa/uiuc-gpa-dataset.csv                i made the Students column by just adding up the numbers in each grade category

Comment: How did you get the `Students` column?

Answer (score 0):

To replicate:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([0.7416332], columns=['PercentageA'])
```

Solution:

```
df.iat[0,0]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you a `Series` or a `DataFrame` with only one value, you can use [`squeeze`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.squeeze.html) to get a scalar value.